# Использование двух сборок, содержащих одинаковое пространство имен

Tags: c#, dll

В проект добавлена ссылка на сборку MyTypesLib_v1.dll:

```
using MyTypesLib;
```

Но в одном модуле есть необходимость в подключении более новой библиотеки.
Добавляю MyTypesLib_v2.dll в  ссылки проекта, пишу:

```
using MyTypesLib;
```

После чего появляется ошибка, что myType существует как в MyTypesLibv1.dll так и в MyTypesLibv2.dll.

**Есть ли способ использовать отличную сборку в отдельном модуле программы без потери в производительности?** (использовать более новую библиотеку не могу).

Данная ошибка и её решение описано [здесь](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/subscriptions/64wh5743(v=vs.90).aspx), но видимо /reference указывается при компиляции библиотеки, а они не мои.

Comment: По вашей ссылке указано верное решение: [использование `alias`'а](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173212.aspx).

Comment: Сколько бьюсь не выходит. При подключении сборки и присвоении ей отличного псевдонима (alias) всё билдится но пишет: "warning MSB3243: Не удается решить конфликт между... сборками.. Выполните переназначение app.config для сборки".

При запуске завершается исключением, пишет: "Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "MyTypesLib_v2" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Главное, проблемы начинаются сразу после добавления ссылки. Может есть другие методы? Проект asp.net

Comment: Проблема ещё в том, что сборки (.dll) имеют одинаковое имя, если её переименовать (+_v2) то будет исключение:

 "Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "MyTypesLib_v2" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну может попробовать `AppDomain`? Только оно может быть неудобно и могут быть конфликты с доступом по доменам (Домен-Домен). Создаешь домен, грузишь либу, обращаешся к ее методам по рефлексии, выгружаешь домен. Но, во всяком случае, если подойдет такой вариант, то работать точно будет.